# 2nd int-casting input-taking variables causes problem

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working in PyCharm. I haven't been programming for a few months and when I came back I saw a problem.

There are 2 user-input-taking variables, input is converted to int.

```
height = int(input())
width = int(input())
```

(it's literally entire code, there's nothing more)

When I run the program and give the 1st integer value, it's still fine, but the 2nd integer causes the following error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

For some reason, it is "ValueError", though I just give it integer value (see screen at the end) and it seems to indicate that I gave it an empty string which is untrue (again, see the screen - I even marked the values I had given; in this case it was 4 and 5).

If I put some code between the 2 variables, like below, the problem doesn't appear:

```
height = int(input())
print(height)
width = int(input())
```

Also note that if it's just one variable, the problem doesn't appear.

And the problem appears only in PyCharm, I did the same in VSCode and everything worked properly. I also reinstalled PyCharm to check if it helps, but it didn't.

I suppose the problem is related to PyCharm, but since hard reinstall (deleting all that Revo Uninstaller found being related to PyCharm) didn't help I have no more ideas...

Visualization:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9609.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please, check your `python --version` in virtual environment (it should be python 3.x)

Comment: You mean python.exe in venv/Scripts? If so, it's 3.10.4

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the code myself (with a few amendments just to see the prompts) and it runs completely fine in my vs code even before my prompt amendments.

```
height = int(input("Input Height: "))
width = int(input("Input Width: "))# Write your code here :-)
area = height * width
print(area)
```

I would suggest checking you have the most update version of python and that everything is configured correctly on your machine.

Also it might help to re-save the file and re run.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue which will be fixed in the next PyCharm version.

See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54238/STDIN-is-lost-for-a-second-input-call

As suggested by the support current workaround is to enable the "Emulate terminal in output console".